# Sending 1 MB Buffer of data over Socket in Android

Tags: java, android, sockets

How can i send a buffer of data whose length is 1 MB over socket in java.
What exactly i am doing is that i want to calculate upload speed of network.For that i want to send  1 MB data to server which i have written in C.

In C to receive and send data we have functions like `send and recv` through which we can send the desired number of bytes by passing the number of bytes to be sent.

```
send(connfd , client_message , `Bytes to send`, 0);
```

but in java i am able to send only 1 byte at a time using

```
int buffer[] = new int[1048576];
PrintWriter output1 = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
output1.print(buffer[1]);
```

so to send multiple bytes i need to call above function again and again. Is there any way in which i can pass whole buffer of 1048576 in on go.

Comment: try with java.nio package

Comment: `byte[] array = new byte[ 1 * 1024 * 1024]; OutputStream os = socket.getOuputStream(); os.write(array); os.flush(); os.close();`

Comment: I think there is a small error: Your buffer would contain 4MB of data, since you have 1024*1024 ints, and an int itself occupies 4byte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `PrintWriter` has a `print(char[] s)` method [(see doc)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#print%28char[]%29). So you could instead create a new char array with the corresponding size (note: a char in Java is 2 byte long) and send that char array using that method.

But there is a better option: A look into [the doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#getOutputStream%28%29) tells us we get an `OutputStream` from our socket. We could wrap that into a [BufferedOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedOutputStream.html), like this:

```
BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
byte buffer[] = new byte[1024*1024];
bos.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
```

And then use `bos.write(byte[], int, int)` to directly send a byte array, which probably would be the most direct way to achieve what you want.